# "Unable to perform link" error when compiling in RAD Studio XE8

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe

The compiler is giving me an error (shown in the pic) even if I run the IDE as an administrator. Can anyone help to solve the problem?

[image: Rad Studio XE8 error]

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Your linker is trying to allocate 128 MB of memory. The following info from Embarcadero was recently posted on the Embarcadero forums:

[Error detected (LME288) in Seattle 10 update 1](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150393)

> The error is an "out of memory", error. The reason for "Out Of Memory"
>   errors (which come in different guises) in the linker, is that **the linker
>   has to pre-allocate memory in contiguous heaps that it then uses as it
>   links, in the past these heaps could not be adjusted, we had to do a best
>   guess, so in the new 64-bit linker (and has also been added to the 32-bit
>   linker) we allowed people to be able adjust the size of these heaps manually
>   when they needed to**. Now the reason why these heaps can be problem is that
>   not all systems are the same, some people use different software that map
>   DLLs into the linker's address space like Windows Hook DLLs, antivirus
>   software all these DLLs allocate memory INSIDE the linker's (any application
>   really) address space and hence has an impact on the size of the heaps the
>   linker can allocate. So we added this ability to adjust the heaps manually,
>   but we also allocated the initial heaps quite big .
>
> **The 32bit linker has a new switch -GH**, see below this is similar to the
>   ilink64 switch.
>
> The syntax for the switch is:
>
> -GH= "
>
> **This option -GH exists from XE3 Update 1 onwards** but evidently is not documented?
>
> To see which heap is out of memory you can try from command line.
>
> MSBuild /p:Platform=Win32 /v:diag XXXX.cbproj
>
> This provides additional information such as:
>
> Overrun on linker heap: code
>
> Linker Heaps
>
> ---
>
> info 0x002d0000 0x0a000000
>
> code 0x000d0000 0x00100000
>
> data 0x00030000 0x08000000
>
> bss 0x08000000 0x08000000
>
> Fatal: Out of memory
>
> The left side of the above output is number of bytes being used at the
>   moment and on the right the number of bytes allocated for the specific named
>   heap.
>
> The default heap sizes the linker allocates at start up are:
>
> "system", default size 0x08000000
>   "info", default size 0x0A000000
>   "code", default size 0x08000000
>   "rodata", default size 0x06000000 //readonly data 
>   "data", default size 0x08000000 
>   "bss", default size 0x08000000 
>   "tds", default size 0x0FA00000
>
> When you see the "unknown heap" this is normally the "tds" heap
>
> Example to adjust tds heap from 0x0FA00000 to 0x0A000000 you would do -GHtds=0x0A000000
>
> Hopefully this information helps you and others with the LME288 error.

You can specify additional flags, such as `-GH`, for the linker in your Project Options.